# Xcode 4.6 Passing selected rows to new UItableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am using `xcode 4.6` to create an iPhone app. 
I have three `ViewControllers` A, B, and C. They are all tableview controllers. I want the user to select multiple rows in `ViewcontrollerA` and `ViewcontrollerB`. Then `ViewControllerC` will show the selected items. Is this possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First you should set `[self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES]` for all your tableviews. From documentation,

`If you call indexPathsForSelectedRows, you can get the index paths that identify the selected rows.`

Assuming you have a ViewControllerA/B * properties in your C, you can do like so:

in ViewControllerC.m:

```
- (void)makeCellsSelected
{
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.viewControllerA indexPathsForSelectedRows]) {
        [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

EDIT Even easier would be as folows:
ViewControllerB.m:

```
ViewControllerC *vcC = [ViewControllerC alloc] init];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]) {
        [[vcC.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:YES];
    }

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcC animated:YES];
```

so your C will appear with already sellected rows